# Google Bigquery on Airflow

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow

I have an error with Google Bigquery with Airflow.
the error message came on running the DAG with BigQueryInsertJobOperator or BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator.

> Failed to execute job 63669 for task gcp_execute_query (403 POST [https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/[PROJECT-ID]/jobs?prettyPrint=false](https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/%5BPROJECT-ID%5D/jobs?prettyPrint=false): Access Denied: Project [PROJECT-ID]: User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project [PROJECT-ID].

1. Created a service account and downloaded a json file. added a content of the json file to a "Extra" field in the connection.
2. The connection itself is working when testing on the 'Connection' page on Airflow.
   and even the query works on my linux command line. ( bq query --use_legacy_sql=false '[QUERY]' ) in docker.
3. my account is showing with the command "gcloud auth list" in docker.
4. and the project id is showing with the command "gcloud projects list" in docker.
5. the user has almost every permissions (roles/bigquery.admin, roles/bigquery.jobUser, roles/bigquery.user, roles/editor) on this project.

only when running a DAG it gives an error like above.
I tried to find similar case on stackoverflow but couldn't.
How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be useful to find a service account which is used to run the DAG job nuder discussion, and check if that service account has relevant IAM roles in regards of the BigQuery (including correct project projects) operations.

Comment: Hello al-dann, thanks for your comment. I already created a service account and downloaded a .json file, and added the content of the json file to the connection 'Extra' field. anyway the 'Test' on the connection page is successful. The error occurs only when the DAG on Airflow.

Comment: If you run the Airflow inside the GCP, there should not be any need for a key json file... Keys might be used only if connection is to be established from outside of the GCP.

Comment: Can you check what IAM roles does the service account under discussion has? Does it have IAM roles to run BigQuery jobs, read/write data, metadata, etc.? Can you check the logs in the GCP?

Comment: My linux server is outside of the GCP and on the command line it works to connect and run query. and connections are well done on the page 'Connection' of Airflow.

Comment: The account has enough IAM roles : BigQuery Admin, BigQuery User, BigQuery Job User, Editor

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Comment: Sorry Vega, was my mistake because it's first time to write a question here